# How can I auto show the help menu?

Tags: receiver

In the game Receiver, there is (currently) no tutorial.  It seems like there are some fairly complex game mechanics, but there is a help screen that tried to show relevant actions.  When you spawn, you can click `?` and it will display this screen.

However, as I have no idea what I'm doing and am still getting used to the controls, I die often.  Is there a way I can just have this help screen automatically display on each respawn instead of having to put `?` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to auto-show the help menu. You will need to press <kbd>/</kbd> every time you respawn.

[image: Help menu]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, maybe try consulting steam for help? Otherwise just try to pace yourself and familiarize the controls one gun at a time.